# C# parse 12 hours time into datetime 24 hours

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I have a list of hours which are in 12 hours format:

```
2:30, 3:00, 4:00, 5:00, 6:00, 7:00, 8:00, 9:00, 10:00, 11:00, 12:00, 
1:00, 2:00, 3:00, 4:00, 5:00, 6:00, 7:00, 8:00, 9:00, 10:00, 11:00, 
12:00, 1:00, 2:00
```

The first value `2:30` is in the night.

If I create a

```
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
```

how can I parse the hours above so that I will create a `List<DateTime>` but with the hours in 24h format?

The thing is the hours are missing `am/pm` information so I don't know how to parse them as 24 hours because otherwise will be duplicates.

Comment: why can't you add the `am/pm` information yourself before parsing it as `DateTime` ? Otherwise there's no way to distinguish

Comment: Is your data ordered? Is the first string the only one with a thirty minute interval from the one following ?

Comment: You cannot, because you don't know if the 12 hour times are AM or PM, unless you have a known (AM/PM) starting point and regular increments

Comment: @Steve: the data is ordered. Yes the first string is the only one with a thirty minute interval, actually can be any value between 01 and 59 but is the only one that is not 00.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: as you can see other comments I know myself that is not possible because is missing am/pm info, therefore I am asking this question because maybe there is a solution which I am not aware of ...

Comment: @user2818430 You can add am/pm yourself before parsing the string to `DateTime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, then if your string data is ordered (and that's a big if) you could try with this code

```
string data = "2:30, 3:00, 4:00, 5:00, 6:00, 7:00, 8:00, 9:00, 10:00, 11:00, 12:00, 1:00, 2:00, 3:00, 4:00, 5:00, 6:00, 7:00, 8:00, 9:00, 10:00, 11:00, 12:00, 1:00, 2:00";
string[] parts = data.Split(',');

DateTime lastInput = DateTime.MinValue;
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
string currentAMPM = "AM";
foreach(string s in parts)
{
    DateTime temp;

    if(DateTime.TryParse(s + " " + currentAMPM, out temp))
    {
        if(temp < lastInput)
        {
            currentAMPM = (currentAMPM == "AM" ? "PM" : "AM");
            DateTime.TryParse(s + " " + currentAMPM, out temp);
        }
        dates.Add(temp);
        lastInput = temp;

    }
}
```